# Is there a way to re-render a functional React.js component without setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a functional React component that needs to be rerendered after I change a slider's position. Since I am using Redux to handle my states, I shouldn't need to use React's because to me it would be a bit of a hacky way to fix my problem. Is there an actual way to rerender said component onChange without converting my component to a classical one?

```
import React from "react";
import { Radio, RadioGroup } from "@material-ui/core";
import Slider from "@material-ui/lab/Slider";

const consoleLog = e => {
  console.log(e.target.name, ": ", e.target.value);
};

const handleData = question => {
  switch (question.type) {
    case "fv":
      return (
        <p
          className="range-field"
          style={{ width: 25 + "%", margin: 25 + "px" }}
        >
          <Slider
            value={25}
            min={question.min}
            max={question.max}
            onChange={consoleLog}
          />
        </p>
      );
  }
};

const Answers = props => {
  return <div>{handleData(props.data)} </div>;
};

export default Answers;
```

Comment: Your component is not connect to Redux. So, it will not update if the redux state changes...

Comment: The component will re-render when either the state changes or it receives new props.

Comment: I actually took out the part where it dispatches, so let's say it does.

Comment: you can use react hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Slider position is actually a state. UI component (`Slider`) is stateless and expect that parent component (`Answers`) handles its state with unidirectional data flow.

In case it's preferable to save UI state in global state, Redux can be used to handle slider state.

Otherwise local state should be used. A component can be converted to a component to use `setState`, it's not hacky to use it because this is actually a state. Or functional components can use React 16.8 hooks:

```
const Answers = props => {
    const [slide, setSlide] = useState(25);
    const onChange = useCallback(e => setSlide(e.value), []);
    const handleData = question => {
      switch (question.type) {
        case "fv":
          return (
            <p
              className="range-field"
              style={{ width: 25 + "%", margin: 25 + "px" }}
            >
              <Slider
                value={slide}
                min={question.min}
                max={question.max}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </p>
          );
      }
    };

    return <div>{handleData(props.data)} </div>;
};
```

Where `useState` preserves slider state between component renders, `useCallback` prevents unnecessary `Slider` rerenders.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. When I go to move the slider, the slide value changes to undefined. It initially works, via changing the starting value but then becomes undefined when I change the value. Error: "The prop `value` is marked as required in `Slider`, but its value is `undefined`".

Answer (score 0):

you can use forceUpdate method to force a rerender.

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: Not something that is recommended though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! So I use React hooks but since I'm using material-ui, I found out the value gets passed alongside the event. So using the code provided by estus, I added value as an extra parameter on the onChange function so I can get my value.

```
const Answers = props => {
const [slide, setSlide] = useState(props.data.min);
const onChange = useCallback((e, value) => setSlide(value), []);
const handleData = question => {
  switch (question.type) {
    case "fv":
      return (
        <p
          className="range-field"
          style={{ width: 25 + "%", margin: 25 + "px" }}
        >
          <Slider
            value={slide}
            min={question.min}
            max={question.max}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </p>
      );
  }
};

return <div>{handleData(props.data)} </div>;
};
```